# Select rows with a duplicate ID but different value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this

[image]

I would like to select the Itemid that occurs more than once with a different Rate with group by Masterid

The output should be something like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might try the following:

```
SELECT masterid, detailid, itemid, rate FROM mytable
WHERE (masterid, detailid, rate) IN
(
    SELECT masterid, detailid, rate FROM mytable t
    JOIN mytable o ON o.masterid = t.masterid
        AND o.detailid = t.detailid AND o.rate <> t.rate
    GROUP BY t.masterid, t.detailid, t.rate
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
)
```

The inner join within the sub-query assures only rows appearing that have an unequal counter part. *Alternatively* you might add another sub-query condition to the outer query:

```
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM mytable o
    WHERE o.masterid = t.masterid AND o.detailid = t.detailid AND o.rate <> t.rate
)
```

Comment: I want only Rows that have rate differences according to MasterID wise in SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a query like below

```
select t1.* from t t1 
join 
(
   select masterid,itemid
   from t
   group by masterid,itemid
   having count(distinct rate )>1
)t2 
   on t1.masterid=t2.masterid and t1.itemid=t2.itemid
order by masterid,detailid
```

and here's a [working db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=14730c94f698a93b55a1e2358d6c4e7f)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
 Select masterid, detailid, rate, count(*) as count from Mytable 
group by masterid, detailid, rate
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.